# Selenium scroll down Facebook page like crash

Tags: python, facebook, selenium, automation

I am trying to scroll down a Facebook page that gives the list of people who have liked a page using selenium and python. The format of url is https://www.facebook.com/search/page_id/likers where page_id is a unique number for each Facebook page.

The page i am trying to scroll down has about 18k likes and as I automate scroll down process, the program crashes when it reaches about 700-800 people.

Here is the error message:

```
Message: unknown error: session deleted because of page crash
from unknown error: cannot determine loading status
from tab crashed
  (Session info: chrome=58.0.3029.110)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.26.436382 (70eb799287ce4c2208441fc057053a5b07ceabac),platform=Linux 4.10.0-32-generic x86_64)
```

Can anyone help me why this is happening?

Comment: _“ am trying to scroll down a Facebook page that gives the list of people who have liked a page ”_ - what for …? If Facebook wanted you to have access to that data in any automated way, they would expose it via API. Using any such automation is a violation of their ToS.

Comment: @CBroe I am not stealing anyone else data. I am just trying to have the list of people who have liked my page by automating the manual process. Is that a violation?

Comment: What do you _want_ with that list? You are not allowed to contact people just because they liked your page or anything like that.

Comment: I know, I have multiple pages and I just want to see how many of them have liked all of them and how many in total are different people liking all of my pages. That's it.

Comment: How are you launching your browser?

Comment: @TarunLalwani I am using Chrome driver

Comment: And you are launching it locally? Through Docker or through Grid?

Comment: Yes locally but I am not using Docker or anything.

Comment: Facebook Terms of Service doesn't allow it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How long is this taking?

Selenium has a default wait time after which point it will return an error, see [this post](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/2606/what-is-seleniums-default-timeout-for-page-loading):

If you are hitting the 30 minute mark you can increase the timeout using

```
driver.set_page_load_timeout(long_wait_time)
```

Comment: Thanks this works. But when I try to get the html using html = driver.page_source, it crashes again. Can you tel why?

Comment: Could be a lot of things, could you show me the error?  If I had to guess, it could be that page_source is huge (since you've been collecting data for over 30 minutes) and you could be running out of ram

Comment: I get this error at the line html = driver.page-source `selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: session deleted because of page crash
from unknown error: cannot determine loading status
from tab crashed
`

Comment: Ok that looks very similar to your first error. It could be to do with the way the page loads (if it's using ajax and you try to save page source during an update maybe?).     

If I were you I'd try incrementally saving the page source. i.e. you save parts of the source rather than trying to do it all at once. I'm not sure how exactly you'd go about doing that, sorry.

Comment: Can you tell me how to save them incrementally?